# Designing Fact table associated with multiple attribute hierarchy members

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, data-warehouse, olap-cube, ssas-2008, fact

I am designing a warehouse to accommodate a movie related database. I have a table with the columns - Title, Genre, SalesAmount, ProductionAmount. 
One such row would be say GodFather, Crime|Drama,1000000,20000.

I want to move this to DW, I am looking at getting this into a Fact table say FactSale and have linkage to Genre dimension.

My objective is to analyze revenues by Genres. In this case, how would I be building the cube matrix? I have another mapping table with TitleId,GenreId present.

Also would it be possible to create a dynamic hierarchy say under Action, Drama, Romance etc. Idea is to gather info on a single genre or combination of genres.

Can someone guide me on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Thanks to the whitepaper from SQLBI with extensive examples and explanations - http://www.sqlbi.com/wp-content/uploads/The_Many-to-Many_Revolution_2.0.pdf